# How can I stream real time video from an IP address using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, video, stream, ip, webcam

I am exploring existing Flutter packages to play video files. Flutter video player example, and Chewie package's example works fine to play video files from an Internet address. However, I am trying to stream data from my computers webcam and for this purpose, I followed an example to stream Raspberry camera video, which use VLC's video streaming package
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tPcuBo5QAW4

I am launcing "motion" command on my Linux laptop and on the browser (http://192.168.2.19:8081) I can see the webcam video. Now I am trying to use the same example as in the video, However, I can not see any streamed video. Instructions to install this command can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/endolith/2052778). Following is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_vlc_player/vlc_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter_vlc_player/vlc_player_controller.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'WebCam Stream'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _streamUrl;
  VlcPlayerController _vlcViewController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _vlcViewController = new VlcPlayerController();
  }

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _streamUrl = (_streamUrl != null) ? null : 'http://192.168.2.19:8081';
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              _streamUrl == null
                  ? Container(
                      child: Center(
                        child: RichText(
                          text: TextSpan(children: [
                            TextSpan(
                              text: 'Stream Closed',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 14.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  background: Paint()..color = Colors.red),
                            )
                          ]),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  : Expanded(
                      child: new VlcPlayer(
                        defaultHeight: 480,
                        defaultWidth: 640,
                        url: _streamUrl,
                        controller: _vlcViewController,
                        placeholder: Container(
                          width: 640,
                          height: 480,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(_streamUrl == null ? Icons.play_arrow : Icons.pause),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Are you giving your app internet permissions ? (just checking)

Comment: Yes in the AndroidManifest xml file :)

Answer (score 0):

Try --web-renderer html and using Image.network(url) since html  renders the video but somehow canvaskit is unable to do it